# Hypermedia Api - Presenting picklist data

Tags: api, rest, hypermedia

I am creating a hypermedia api that conforms to the HAL spec

When a user submits a payment they need to specify what type of card they are using (Visa, Master Card etc)

So for a particular field that is submitted there is a specific list of values that can be used

How do I present that pick list to the user?

As embedded data?

Is there generally a way to associate a field with a given set of data?

I realise the HAL spec is very small and doesnt cover this issue specifically. But in general hypermedia apis how do people usually present this data?

Or should I simply explain the field in the CURIE link?
thanks

Comment: Are the card types just names? What about a simple list of card type names?

Comment: yes - it will be  a list of strings. Im just wondering about how to associate that list with a given field. so you know that field can only be a value from the list

Answer (score 0):

You are right, HAL does not specifically cover this issue. You can solve this by essentially copying `HTML`. There are different widgets defined in `HTML` to present stuff, for example a combobox with listed options.

You can define a `media-type` that has similar controls in it, and you can define the processing model for the `media-type` as well. It can be a `json` representation of course, does not need to be `xml`.

For example

```
{
    ...
    "cardType": {
       "inputType": "select",
       "possibleValues": ["Visa", "MasterCard", ... ]
    }
    ...
}
```

There is no ready-made format that I know of unfortunately.